# Javascript <script> inside PHP echo : won't execute

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, echo

I have a weird issue with a javascript script that won't run inside my php echo. The script shows in the source page but doesn't run.
My file is in a iframe (facebook app), I am using firefox and firebug.

I have a function returning my script as a string, and then I echo this function.

```
function myFunction($request_token){
    if ($count == 0){
        return "<script>console.log(\"run??\");</script><a href=\"blabla\"></a>";
    }
}
```

When I look at the source code I see

```
<script>
    console.log("run??");
</script>
<a href="blabla"></a>
```

which seems fine, but nothing shows up in the console. I tried to do an alert, won't work either.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Try `<script type="text/javascript">`. Do you have any other scripts on the page that might throw errors? (scripts are executed in serial, if one throws you're done).

Comment: I tried to add text/javascript, doesn't work either. I have other scripts + the facebook scripts, but no error shows up in the console

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing `<script>` to `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: Does this help if I say that I load my file with the echo from javascript like that : 
xmlhttp.open("GET","php/myFile.php?request=init,true);
xmlhttp.send();

Then in myFile.php I echo myFunction

Comment: @nax_ - So you have a page that uses JavaScript to use AJAX to call a a PHP page to return JavaScript?

Comment: Yes I do. 
Sounds stupid now that you say it but yeah that's how it works.
By the way, as you might have guessed xmlhttp is a XMLHttpRequest()